# How to Customize Spring Authorization Server token_endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to customize the token endpoint URL in Spring Security 6.X from the default `/oauth2/token` to something else. While I've configured the oAuth2TokenEndpointFilter, it doesn't seem to be taking effect. Can you help me understand how to properly add this filter to the filter chain for the desired URL change?

```java
@Bean
public OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter oAuth2TokenEndpointFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    String tokenEndpointUri = "/oauth2/custom/token";
    return new OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter(authenticationManager, tokenEndpointUri);
}
```

Comment: [I wouldn't do that if I were you.](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/oauth)

Comment: @BillHorvath Can you explain why ?

Comment: [The document that I provided the link to](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/oauth#endpoints) explains that it's part of the oauth specification. If you somehow manage to change it, you'll likely break a lot of things.